# BigInteger Простые числа

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, простые-числа

Увлёкся недавно простыми числами и мне понадобилась программка для проверки числа на простоту.

Проверяю огромное количество чисел и работаю за пределами long. Первый раз работаю с BigInteger. Поэтому был бы рад услышать мнения по поводу эффективности кода. Можно ли здесь где-нибудь увеличить производительность?

Алгоритм прост:

- проверка равно ли 0,1,2 или меньше ли нуля.
- проверка делится ли без остатка на хотя бы одно нечётное начиная от 3 до квадратного корня самого числа.

Код:

```
public static boolean isPrime(BigInteger number) {
    if (number.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number should be positive");

    if (number.toString().equals("1") || number.toString().equals("0"))
        return false;

    // if the number is even return FALSE, unless the number is "2".
    if (isEven(number)) {
        if (number.toString().equals("2")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    long limit = sqrt(number).longValue();
    // A loop for searching a divider. If no divider found - return "true".
    for (long i = 3; limit >= i; i += 2) {
        // if (number % i == 0)
        if (number.mod(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i))).toString().equals("0")) {
            // System.out.println("The first divider is " + i);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public static boolean isEven(BigInteger number) {
    if ((number.and(new BigInteger("1"))).toString().equals("0"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger N) {
    final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");

    BigInteger result = N.divide(TWO);
    while (result.multiply(result).subtract(N).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE.divide(new BigInteger("100000000"))) > 0)
        result = result.add(N.divide(result)).divide(TWO);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: А зачем писать свой метод? Можно использовать `isProbablePrime()`, а потом проверять каким-нибудь тестом простоты, что это действительно простое число.

Comment: Так именно этот тест простоты я здесь и пытаюсь написать.:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Не нужно сравнивать строковые представления `BigInteger`, так вы можете напороиться на то, что `"2".compareTo("10") == 1`, да и постоянные конвертации `BigInteger -> String` будут снижать производительность. Сравнивайте сами `BigInteger`'ы: `BigInteger.ONE.equals(number)` или `BigInteger.valueOf(2).equals(number)` или `new BigInteger("2").equals(number)`. `BigInteger.valueOf(2)` предпочтительнее, так как этот метод закеширует результат и не будет каждый раз пересоздавать объект `BigInteger` (актуально для чисел в диапазоне `[-16, 16]`).
2. Выделите `new BigInteger("100000000")` в константу, так вы избежите постоянного пересоздания этого объекта. Вообще, у вас какая-то каша с константными `BigInteger`'ами: то вы используете константу `BigInteger.ONE`, то создаёте новый объект `new BigInteger("1")`. Приведите всё к константам.
3. Заведите привычку, сравнивая объекты через `equals` первым писать тот объект, который гарантированно не `null`, в вашем случае - константы, с которыми вы сравниваете числа.
4. Вы проверяете на простоту `BigInteger`'ы, а в качестве верхней границы для проверуи делителей у вас `long`. На больших числах (от 3 037 000 500 и больше) ваш код перестанет работать из-за переполнения `long`'а. Делайте цикл со счётчиком `BigInteger`.
5. Ваш метод `isEven` можно записать короче и оптимальнее: `return number.getLowestSetBit() != 0;`.
6. Вообще, конструкции вида

   ```
   if (/* условие */) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
   ```

   – не самая лучшая практика. Если кроме `return` в блоках кода ничего нет и не предвидится, лучше заменять такие конструкции на `return /* условие */;`. Если условие слишком сложное, его разбивают на несколько подусловий, присваивая их значения переменным с говорящими именами.
7. Оптимизация: для сокращения числа расчётов можно использовать метод `isProbablePrime` (как предложил @Arsenicum) или самостоятельно реализовать [вероятностную проверку Миллера-Рабина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) (если вы стремитесь поглубже вникнуть в математическую часть задачи).
8. Ещё оптимизация: можно реализовать [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) - так вы избежите ненужных проверок на делимость, но существенно увеличите потребление памяти.